Rearrange / Reorder Columns in Excel based on the headers which are numbers
I have an excel file which consists of headers with Numbers like below and I want them to be reordered in an Ascending order from left to right including the column data with an excel macro. can someone help with same

I have got the below piece of code but it doesn't fit the purpose, I need to rearrange the columns in ascending order from left to right


Sub Sort_Cols()
  Dim rngAddress As Range
  Dim myCols
  Dim i As Long
  
  myCols = Split("Obj 2|Obj 4|Obj 1|Obj 3", "|")  '<- In the order you want them in columns A:D
  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 0 To UBound(myCols)
      Set rngAddress = Nothing
      Set rngAddress = .Range("A1:Z1").Find(myCols(i))
      If rngAddress Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox myCols(i) & " column was not found."
        Exit Sub
      Else
        .Range(rngAddress, rngAddress.End(xlDown)).Cut
        On Error Resume Next
        .Columns(i + 1).Insert
        On Error GoTo 0
      End If
    Next i
  End With
End Sub




Perhaps loop backwards and use.Columns(A:A").Insert, then remove columns E through H?

Sort can sort your data column-wise on your column headers - try recording a macro and that will give you a good starting point

Thanks for your response, but I need to rearrange / reorder the columns and not rows and that too with the data .i.e. entire columns needs to be reordered/rearranged alongwith the header rows and not just the header row


Excel built-in sort function works well for your case

Sub SortRows()
    With Range("A2:F5") ' modify as needed
        .Sort key1:=.Rows(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, Orientation:=xlSortRows
    End With
End Sub



Thanks for your response, but I need to rearrange / reorder the columns and not rows and that too with the data .i.e. entire columns needs to be reordered/rearranged alongwith the header rows and not just the header row

It is sorting the all table. You need to change Range("A2:F5") to include the table.

Sub SortColumns()
    With Range("Table1") ' modify as needed
        .Sort key1:=.Rows(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, Orientation:=xlSortColumns
    End With
End Sub


I tried above but it didn't work

The argument should be Header:=xlNo, Orientation:=xlSortRows

Yes, I did try with that first but it didn't work so I changed it xlYes and xlSortColumns but even that didn't work

The argument works well for the data which is shared on your screenshot. Have you tried it?

I've uploaded a screenshot of my testing.
